# Is there a way to block "vagrant up" command when some project files are missing

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm developing vagrant environment for my team. One of the assumptions is that database has to be outside the machine. So every team member has to install his own MySQL server on his own local machine and create file local.yaml (puppet) with database configuration. The problem is that not every member reads my instructions and after minutes of building there are db errors (no database found etc.). I would like to add some info before someone run command "vagrant up".

Question: Is there a way to block vagrant up when there is no local.yaml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have a check for the `local.yaml` file in your Vagrantfile and then `raise` if it doesn't exist

I think the code would look something like this:

```
...
raise 'You need a local.yaml' unless File.exist?('local.yaml')
...
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    ...
```

Usage:

```
$ vagrant up
There was an error loading a Vagrantfile. The file being loaded
and the error message are shown below. This is usually caused by
a syntax error.

Path: /Users/<username>/<workspace>/<project>/Vagrantfile
Line number: 0
Message: RuntimeError: You need a local.yaml
```

Comment: it can even check the db is running on host .. ``unless `ps aux | grep <mysql process> != ""``

Comment: @FrédéricHenri indeed, you can

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot :)